# Index ranges/slices given by two numpy index arrays

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have a data vector `x`, and two index vectors `left` and `right`. The values in `left` and `right` correspond the the lower and upper values of the slice I want to define.

I could write something like:

```
for l, r in zip(left, right):
     z = x[l:r]
     # Compute with z here
```

But this would be slower than any hypothetical numpy solution, as indexing or iterating numpy arrays in python is generally slow. To see this compare

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; x = np.arange(1000)" "np.sum(x)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.9 usec per loop
```

to

```
python3 -m timeit -s "import numpy as np; x = np.arange(1000)" "sum(x)"
10000 loops, best of 3: 69 usec per loop
```

Thus any python iteration over left and right will slow things down. I would like to know if it is possible to do this using more idiomatic numpy based indexing and tools.

EDIT:

There is a solution for a less general instance of the problem. If you have `left` and `right` such that `left[n + 1] == right[n]` for all `0 < n < len(left) + 1`, then `left` and `right` form a partition of `x`. The split points can be represented by a single array of indices. In this case you can use [numpy.split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html).

Comment: Would the slice length be same across all iterations?

Comment: @Divakar No, slice lengths can be of arbitrary positive length.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail of what you are looking for? A little more description may be helpful.

Comment: I guess you could do : `for i in range(left):  z = x[left[i]:right[i]]`, not sure if its any better on performance though if that's what you're after.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this can be sped up. Besides, it would only be beneficial if you could vectorize the postprocessing; but that won't be easy (potentially impossible) if your slices can have varying length. `x[l:r]` is perfectly fine with numpy.

Comment: Regarding your edit: do you have 10000 slices? Is there a reason why you think that this is a performance bottleneck in your application?

Comment: Also, if you are looking for performance, maybe the computations involving  `z` could be done in a vectorized fashion by getting those indices as full or getting a full mask, but that depends on what the computation is.

Comment: What do you want to do with the slices?  Sum them up?  Multiply them?  If you want to sum them up, you can take the cumulative sum of `x` and let `left` and `right` define the spots in which to slice and difference.  Point is, there may be a way to make this all faster if you let us know what else is happening down stream.

Comment: Are your slices allowed to overlap? Because if not and they are ordered you could try and use split on `np.c_[left,right].ravel() and then discard every other slice.